# Strange Behavior of POST in PHP for DynamoDb

Tags: php, post, backend, amazon-dynamodb

When I make a POST request, the DynamoDb does not want to return me any values for the item. Notice that I have hard coded the key.

If its the POST request, then the value is null, but if executed as a script, correct answer is returned. In both cases, the item_id checks out to be the same (say 999).

Any idea as to why there is a null result in case of a POST ?

```
if($_POST){
    $item_id = getID($_COOKIE['_cookie']);
}
else{
    $item_id = 999;
}
if($item_id!=null){
//$item_id is totally fine in both cases. Verified by echoing output

$res = $client->getItem(array(
    'ConsistentRead' => false,
    'TableName' => 'table123',
    'Key'  => array(
        'item_id'   => array('N' => 999)
        )
    ));

 echo $res['Item']['user_id']['N'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead in getItem :  'item_id' => array ('N' =>'999') i.e add single quotes

There is an example under **Retrieving items** section of the PHP SDK guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/aws-sdk-php-guide.pdf. Check page 45.
It may provide more information. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just for future notice, I think this answer would serve better as a comment since it is just a suggestion and a link to documentation - not a definite solution and explanation.